# Using the correct way to Synchronized to avoid data loss

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to create an ATM system with multi-threaded to avoid data loss of the withdrawl requests.

I've created 2 Threads that each one of them try to withdrawl `1000-5000` money from the bank balance.

I dont want the Threads to work together, I want each one of them to wait for the second Thread to finish working.
Both of the Threads should stop withdraw money when the balance is 0, or the withdrawl request is higher than the current balance.

My problem is that I see the Thread1 run 4 times instand letting the Thread2 get in, and so on with Thread2, its seem they not waiting for each other to enter action.

Main:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bank bank = new Bank(100000);
        ThreadSync threadSync = new ThreadSync();
        Thread client1 = new ClientThread(bank, threadSync,1);
        Thread client2 = new ClientThread(bank, threadSync,2);


        client1.start();
        client2.start();
    }
}
```

Bank:

```
public class Bank {
    private int balance;
    public Bank(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

ClientThread:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private Bank bank;
    private ThreadSync threadSync;
    private int client;

    ClientThread(Bank bank, ThreadSync threadSync, int client) {
        this.bank = bank;
        this.threadSync = threadSync;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int randomNumber;
        while (bank.getBalance() > 0) {
            synchronized (threadSync) {
                randomNumber = ((int) (Math.random() * (5000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000);
                try {
                    if (bank.getBalance() - randomNumber >= 0) {
                        bank.setBalance(bank.getBalance() - randomNumber);
                    }
                    System.out.println(client + " - " + bank.getBalance() + " withdrawed - " + randomNumber);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadSync:

```
public class ThreadSync {
    public void send(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println("Sending\t"  + msg );
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + msg + "Sent");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *I dont want the Threads to work together, I want each one of them to wait for the second Thread to finish working.*  Threads are used to support concurrent processing (doing things common between the threads but in a non-interferring way).  It seems to me that you would be best doing this sequentially.  And you didn't explain the problem you are having.

Comment: @WJS, I've updated the question, what do you mean by saying sequenttially?

Comment: One thread after the other.  Or doing one task after the the other rather than concurrently (at or nearly at the same time but without interferring with each other).. For example, many different customer should be able to take out and deposit money at the same time (concurrent processing) instead of having to wait for each other to finish their transaction before someone else can start (sequential processing).

Comment: If I will let the Thread to finish his task there is no money left for the Thread2

Comment: Insufficient funds should be handled by each thread as they attempt to take out money.  In some cases it could be a first come first served situation.

Comment: Do you think the `while` loop is needed? there is a way of making a thread repeating of his `run()` over and over again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216980/discussion-between-itzikb-and-wjs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but you should know that this is a Bad Pattern:

```
while (...trivial test...) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...something that takes some time...
    }
}
```

The problem is that each time the loop releases the lock, almost the very next thing that it does is re-lock it again. If thread A gets in to the loop, and then thread B subsequently *tries* to get in, it's very likely that thread B will be *[starved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))*.

When thread B attempts to enter the synchronized block, it will be *[swapped out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)* (a.k.a., "blocked", "put to sleep") by the operating system.

When thread A releases the lock, it takes time for the OS to swap thread B back in again. Meanwhile, thread A already has a running head start: It re-locks the lock, goes back to work, and by the time thread B ready to run, it's already too late. The OS will swap B out once more, and the same thing will likely happen on the next iteration, and the next, ...

---

The trick is to re-structure your program so that the threads never need to keep the lock locked for any significant amount of time. It may sound paradoxical, but sometimes you can speed up a parallel computation by making the threads do *extra* work if the extra work enables them to keep out of each other's way.

If you can't re-structure the program such that most of the actual work happens outside of  the critical sections (that is, the "locked" sections), then that may be a sign that the problem you are trying to solve is not well suited to a multi-threaded solution.